# Get all unique numbers in MySQL table using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to build an archive list for a blog using php and mysql. The problem is I am not sure of the best way to do this.

I was hoping there was a way to get a list of years and than display them so lets say my table has `id | year | content` and has the current rows

```
1 | 2013 | content
2 | 2013 | content
3 | 2013 | content
4 | 2012 | content
5 | 2012 | content
6 | 2011 | content
```

is it possible to make a mysql statement that well only return IDs `1,4,6`, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     select * from table
     group by year
```

if you consider the order then add this in the end `order by id`

[**DEMO here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df0f/1)

you can also get the specified Id by using `Min` or `Max`. like this

```
   select min(id) ,year ,content from table
     group by year
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df0f/17)

Comment: I can't believe I always forget about `GROUP BY`. This works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Just a word of caution on this answer. When you're selecting columns that are not specified in the 'group by' clause (in this case 'content' and 'id'), MySQL does not define which row will be used to give the returned values for those columns.  So, for instance, for 2013, you might get id=1 or you might get id=3 - it is indeterminate.  This sort of syntax is really intended for use where the values in such column would all be the same, so it makes no difference which one is returned.  Of course, you may not care which is returned - but then its better not to return them at all.

Comment: its automatically will get the lowest id , if he wants get the bigger id , then he need to use max(id) , but here no need for min(id)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's indeterminate without a group by function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Hey - what you've changed it to now also does not do what you might expect and could be very confusing.  If you 'select min(id), year, content ... group by year' what you get is the minimum id but then an indeterminate selection of the column 'content' from that group.  But I think we're overcomplicating the original question! ... Robert - aren't you just after a list of years in your table?  Do you care about bringing back a min or max row for that year?

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id) , year from table group by year
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get a list of the 'year's in your table:

```
select distinct year from table
```

Depending on the size of your table and how often you're running the query, you could think about indexing on 'year'.